# Помогите определить вид предложения

Tags: недопустимая-метка

"когда слитно, когда раздельно" - Объясните, пожалуйста, что это за вид предложения (безличное? бессоюзное сложное? как найти грамм основу/ы?)

Comment: А это точно предложение? Больше похоже на отрывок из него.

Comment: Приведите контекст!